# Reactive mongo fails to store BigInt

Tags: mongodb, playframework, bigdecimal, reactivemongo

I'm using Play (2.4) with reactive mongo. I'm trying to save following document using reactive mongo:

```
{        
    "networkStart" : 42540528726795050063891204319802818560,
    "networkEnd" : 42540528726795654526801011634390171648,
    "lat" : 36.0833,
    "lon" : 140.116
}
```

using following code

```
val record = GeoIP(... networkStart, networkEnd, lat, lng ...)
val collection: JSONCollection = reactiveMongoApi.db.collection[JSONCollection]("mycolleciton")

collection.save(Json.toJson(record)).map{ r =>
  Logger.error(s"Has err: ${r.hasErrors}")
}
```

but nothing happens. There is no document in mongo DB and there is no error log in logs. When i try to save record with lower numbers e.g. `16777216` in place of `network*` attributes everything works fine.

Same for searching. When i search using query e.g. `{networkStart: {$lte #someNum#}}` for `#someNum#` equals to very big integer i get exception `[NoSuchElementException: JsError.get]`. When i search for lower number i get correct results.

**Am i managing big numbers incorrectly? How can i store them and retrieve using reactive mongo?** When i try to insert document with big number manually directly into DB it works.

### Edit

I managed to get validation error by debugging. It says:

```
(,List(ValidationError(List(List((,List(ValidationError(List(List((,List(ValidationError(List(List((,List(ValidationError(List(List((,List(ValidationError(List(unhandled json value: 85060714218195519117058029889198843855),WrappedArray()))))),WrappedArray()))))),WrappedArray()))))),WrappedArray()))))),WrappedArray())))
```

where the most interesting part is: `List(unhandled json value: 85060714218195519117058029889198843855)`. **But why?**

Comment: Get the `NoSuchElementException` wrapped in the `JsError` and do a `.printStackTrace()`

Comment: What `Format` are you using to serialize GeoIP?

Comment: @Bilk `implicit val geoIpFormat = Json.format[GeoIP]`